# Recovering Json object custom value

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3.js and I'm having some dificulties to recover an custom parameter of Json object.

I'm already can recover the value of `x` and `y` of my `multiBarChart` by doing `d.x` and `d.y`.

But now I'm trying to **recover a custom parameter**, like the color value that I can pass by parameter of Json Object, but unsuccessfully.

Someone already done something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Try d.color, if you have more than one set, d[0].color. If this doesn't work, can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: Can you copy and paste your data? And, here is a handy tool to check whether its a valid JSON http://jsonlint.com.